# Is there any way to put my custom name to LIB folder which i am going to place in WEB-INF folder of struts application?

Tags: java, struts2

Is there any way to put my custom name to LIB folder which i am going to place in WEB-INF folder of struts application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Or yes… if you don't want its contents on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

And why on earth you wanna do that? FYI, its `lib` not `LIB`.